# Initial conditions with a non-linear ODE in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, ode

I'm trying to use Mathematica's NDSolve[] to compute a geodesic along a sphere using the coupled ODE:

```
x" - (x" . x) x = 0
```

The problem is that I can only enter initial conditions for x(0) and x'(0) and the solver is happy with the solution where x" = 0.  The problem is that my geodesic on the sphere has the initial condition that x"(0) = -x(0), which I have no idea how to tell mathematica.  If I add this as a condition, it says I'm adding True to the list of conditions.

Here is my code:

```
s1 = NDSolve[{x1''[t] - (x1[t] * x1''[t] + x2[t] * x2''[t] + x3[t]*x3''[t]) * x1[t] == 0, x2''[t] -  (x1[t] * x1''[t] + x2[t] * x2''[t] + x3[t]*x3''[t]) * x2[t] == 0, x3''[t] - (x1[t] * x1''[t] + x2[t] * x2''[t] + x3[t]*x3''[t]) * x3[t] == 0, x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 0, x1'[0] == 0, x2'[0] == 0, x3'[0] == 1} , { x1, x2, x3}, {t, -1, 1}][[1]]
```

I would like to modify this so that the initial acceleration is not zero but `-x(0)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem through a mathematical rearrangement rather than addressing my original issue:

Let V(t) be a vector field along x(t).

x . V = 0 implies d/dt (x . V) = (x' . V) + (x . V') = 0

So the equation D/dt V = V' - (x . V') x = V' + (x' . V) x holds
This means the geodesic equation becomes:  x" + (x' . x') x = 0 and so it can be solved using the initial conditions I originally had.

Thanks a lot Janus for going through and pointing out the various problems I was having including horrible code layout, I learnt a lot through your re-writing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error message says -- NDSolve only accepts initial conditions for derivatives of orders strictly less than the maximal order appearing in the ODE.
I have a feeling this is more of a mathematics question. Mathematically, `{x''[0]=-x0, x[0]==x0}`, doesn't define a unique solution - you'd have to do something along the lines of `{x0.x''[0]==-1,  x[0]==x0, x'[0]-x0 x0.x'[0]==v0}` for that to work out (NDSolve would still fail with the same error). You do realize you will just get a great circle on the unit sphere, right?

By the way, here is how I would have coded up your example:

```
x[t_] = Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {j, 3}];
s1 = NDSolve[Flatten[Thread /@ #] &@{
       x''[t] - (x''[t].x[t]) x[t] == {0, 0, 0},
       x[0] == {1, 0, 0}, 
       x'[0] == {0, 0, 1}
     }, x[t], {t, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks Janus,

What I was ultimately trying to do is solve some differential equations on the unit sphere using mathematica.   The simplest DE I thought I'd try was D/dt x' = 0, ie) the geodesic equation to hopefully get a great circle arc like you suggested :).  On a sphere in R^n, the covariant derivative D/dt V be calculated by V' - <V', x> x and with this formula I have no need of going into charts.   So with this motivation in mind, is there some way of telling mathematica that I'm working on the sphere and don't want solutions that aren't on it?